# Getting Resque Status to work with jRuby

Tags: ruby, rake, jruby, resque

I have an application which I've already implement `Resque` for background jobs. Alos, I'm using gem `resque-scheduler` and `resque-status` and they are all work smoothly on `Ruby 1.9.2`.

My application is a Sinatra app and I've made my `Rakefile` and here its

```
require "resque/tasks"
require "resque_scheduler/tasks"
```

Now, I'm trying to run the application under `jruby 1.6.3 (ruby-1.8.7-p330)`, but unfortunately, I got a problem when I tried to run `COUNT=2 VERBOSE=true QUEUE=* rake resque:workers`.

The terminal threw this error "after adding `--trace` to the rake command"

```
rake aborted!
can't convert Class into String
org/jruby/RubyFile.java:872:in `basename'
org/jruby/RubyFile.java:1069:in `extname'
(eval):3:in `extname_with_potential_path_argument'
/Users/amr/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:561:in `load_imports'
/Users/amr/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:502:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/amr/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/amr/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/amr/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/amr/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `run'
/Users/amr/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/amr/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/amr/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1063:in `load'
/Users/amr/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3@global/bin/rake:19:in `(root)'
```

I tracked My projects files to find that when I remove `require "resque/job_with_status"` from some file It all work well and get the expected error `i.e. Resque::JobWithStatus couldn't be found`.

I tried to run `jruby --1.9 -S rake ...` but it also doesn't work!

So is there any way to get `resque-status` to work with jRuby?

and I've already opened an issue on github: https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status/issues/45

Thanks in advance